# How do I point my domain to another dns server?

Tags: dns, web, cpanel

Currently there's 2 domains `www.mywebsite.com` & `www.mywebsite2.com` each have their own dns server.

I want to point `www.mywebsite.com` to refer to dns server of `www.mywebsite2.com`.

How do I do that? I'm using cpanel hosting platform.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this through your domain provider, such as GoDaddy, NameCheap, NetworkSolutions, etc. they would have a control panel/configuration management tool for your domain name that would allow you to make advanced DNS server changes like the one you are looking to do. All of them have detailed documentation and step-by-step instructions to perform this function.